# Mirror databases on different version

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two sql servers

1. Windows Server 2008R2 SQL Server 2012
2. Windows Server 2012R2 SQL Server 2016

I want to mirror one of the databases to the other.

Will it work on different sql versions or cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

The summary is-

The principal and mirror server instances **must be running on the same version of SQL Server**. While it is possible for the mirror server to have a higher version of SQL Server, this configuration is only recommended during a carefully planned upgrade process. In such a configuration, you run the risk of an automatic failover, in which data movement is automatically suspended because data cannot move to a lower version of SQL Server.

For more details, please visit [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/prepare-a-mirror-database-for-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

> Will it work on different SQL Versions or cause problems?

Yes, but it will work only when Primary is **Lower** and Secondary is **Higher version**, as it already confirmed by MkRabbani, you need to plan it accordingly.

Consider, by any chance if fail-over happened the database cannot be reverted back (by fail-over again). So, it's possible but depends on your scenario how do you want use Mirroring, [Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) etc.. as all work in same manner (always lower to higher version possible, but not higher to lower).